# Displaying a List of objects in a MVC view page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i am working on a school project and i am stuck.
What i want to do is.. by pressing a button on a page to call a method that executes a read sql query. Then it creates Model objects filled with info from the query and puts them in a list. Once the list is filled it should return a view where all the Objects are displayed. 
(in my case the view will show all "orders" existent in the sql database)

Code of my button (my method is called: LaadBestellingen, my Controller is called Beheer:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("LaadBestellingen", "Beheer")'"> LOAD ORDERS </button>
```

This is the BeheerController method:

```
public ActionResult LaadBestellingen()
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT voornaam, achternaam, adres, postcode, email, telefoon, totaalprijs , datum FROM bestelling b JOIN klant k ON k.idklant = b.idklant JOIN product p ON p.idproduct = b.idproduct;";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<Bestelling> bestellingenlijst = new List<Bestelling>();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Bestelling bestelling = new Bestelling();

                bestelling.Klantvoornaam = dataReader.GetString("voornaam");
                bestelling.Klantachternaam = dataReader.GetString("achternaam");
                bestelling.Klantadres = dataReader.GetString("adres");
                bestelling.Klantpostcode = dataReader.GetString("postcode");
                bestelling.Klantemail = dataReader.GetString("email");
                bestelling.Klanttelefoon = dataReader.GetString("telefoon");
                bestelling.Totaalprijs = dataReader.GetDouble("totaalprijs");

                bestellingenlijst.Add(bestelling);

            }


                return View(bestellingenlijst);


        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write("Er is een fout opgetreden tijdens laden van de bestellingen", e);
            return View("Index");

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

And finally this is the code for of my view, it has the same name as the method LaadBestellingen:

```
@using WebWinkelGroep16.Models;
@model List<Bestelling>
```

Skipping a bit of html code, and here suposes to be the content where it displays:

```
 <div id="content">
        <ul>
            @{
                foreach (Bestelling element in @Model)
                {                      
                     <li>   Voornaam: @element.Klantvoornaam <br /> </li>
                      <li>  Achternaam: @element.Klantachternaam<br /></li>
                       <li> Adres: @element.Klantadres<br /></li>
                       <li>  Postcode: @element.Klantpostcode<br /></li>
                     <li>   Email: @element.Klantemail <br /></li>
                     <li>   Telefoon: @element.Klanttelefoon<br /></li>
                     <li>   Totaalprijs: @element.Totaalprijs<br /></li>

                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

What am i doing wrong? When i try to execute the SQL query it works as a charm and shows all info that is asked off it. It always sends me to the return view in the catch for some reason.

Comment: What exception are you getting? If its going into the catch block then something is going wrong. Step into it and post the exception message. This will enable us to help more

Comment: thats the problem.. its my first time working with MVC and Visual Studio. Until now i was doing only java in netbeans enviroment where every execption got caught in the console. Here i dont even know where to look for the exception... :/

Comment: Click on the return View line in the exception block, press F9, this will turn the line red, now press F5 and the project should run, when it gets to the red line it will stop and you can hover your mouse over the letter e and you can check its value. Do some reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Comment: it says: + {"Unknown column 'datum' in 'field list'"} System.Exception {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException}

Comment: But i am not even SELECTING that field in my query or anywhere at all..

Answer (score 0):

If you write your query like this:

```
String selectQuery = @"SELECT voornaam
, achternaam
, adres
, postcode
, email
, telefoon
, totaalprijs 
, datum 
FROM bestelling b 
JOIN klant k ON k.idklant = b.idklant 
JOIN product p ON p.idproduct = b.idproduct;";
```

You will see that you actually select `datum` column. Just delete it. And see what's happened.

Comment: wow thanks i cant believe i could have been so blind.. i have red my code like 100x times. Ill write my queries like you from now on lol.

Comment: Or use an orm or use stored procedures!

Comment: @matt_lethargic right, it's better to use orm for your logic